# Are those wording/representation incorrect?- Conditioning a random variable on an event

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability

[image]

[Conditioning a random variable on an event](https://jrom.ece.gatech.edu/wp-content/uploads/sites/436/2017/08/13_ConditionalRVs-su14.pdf)

**Not trying to be criticising.**

I am cross-reading the same chapter from different books, and I felt those formulas were integral with respect to the set that is not consistent, or my understanding went wrong a bit, I am not sure are those considered correct?

For example, the first integration: I think that should be all Borel image of $B$ in $\mathbb{R}$ that is defined by $X$

Are those writing considered acceptable?

Sincerely ask for what you considered the correct form, respectively.

---

Here is what I think
$$
P(B|A)=\int_{\hat{B}}f_{X|A}(x)dx\quad\text{for any borel}\,\hat{B}\subset\mathbb{R} \,\text{defined by} X(B)=\hat{B}
$$

Comment: What does "all Borel image of $B$ in $\mathbb{R}$ that is defined by $X$" mean? And when you say "that should be", what exactly is "that" ?

Comment: @Ted re-editted

Comment: I still don't totally understand what you mean but perhaps you what are writing is just an expansion of the definition of the integral given in the text.

Comment: @Ted What I meant was how come integrate density over $B$, which is an event, a subset of sample space. The only way over event $B$ has to be w.r.t probability measure. Put differently, there is no *density* concept on sample space, you can only integrate density over $\mathbb{R}$